# How do I make an array of the indices where the previous value did not meet a condition?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, iteration, enumerate

I have two arrays (`v_1` and `v_2`), and I have a function that takes these arrays, finds the indices where their values exceed a threshold, finds the previous and next values of the array, and returns a new array (`v_1f` and `v_2f`) containing the indices where the previous value did not meet the threshold.

However, for some reason the `return` statement is not giving me these arrays. Why is that? Also, should this function produce an array with the conditions that I want?

```
def findbursts(v_1,v_2):

  for index, obj in enumerate(v_1):
      if obj == thresh:
          v_1f=(obj).nonzero()[0]
          # TODO Bounds-checking
          previous = v_1f[index - 1]
          if previous == None:
              v_1ff = v_1f

  for index, obj in enumerate(v_2):
      if obj == thresh:
          v_2f=(obj).nonzero()[0]
          # TODO Bounds-checking
          previous = v_2f[index - 1]
          if previous == None:
              v_2ff = v_2f

  return [v_1ff, v_2ff]
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `return` statement in the second `for` loop.  Are you sure that should be there?

Comment: Oops. No it shouldn't have been, but it still doesn't work. I also updated the function to do what I want... I think.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some sample data and the desired result to allow us to verify we understand your requirements

Comment: you say "...their values exceed a threshold", but you are testitng gor `obj == thresh`

Comment: Are you familiar with [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)? At a glance, it looks like `numpy` would be more suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You probably want `obj >= thresh`, using `==` doesn't match your problem description.
2. Why are you comparing the previous value to `None`? You need to check if it's `< thresh`
3. Can you clarify what the `nonzero()` call is for?
4. You're not actually creating arrays inside your loop. `v_1ff` and `v_2ff` are single values.
   One way to fix it would be creating lists beforehand (`v_1ff = []`) and then append the found value to the list when it matches the condition.
5. `v_1ff` is actually the previous *value*, not the previous *index* -- which do you want?
6. If you're performing the exact same operation on two lists, it'd be cleaner to make a function that does it for a single list and then just call it twice.

You can probably do all this much more easily with a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import izip

def find_bursts(data, thresh):
    return [i for i, (val, next_val) in enumerate(izip(data[:-1], data[1:])) 
            if val < thresh and next_val >= thresh]
```

Breakdown:

- `izip(data([:-1], data[1:])` iterates over your array as pairs of adjacent elements
- `enumerate` attaches the indices
- `if val < thresh and next_val >= thresh` is your filter condition

Comment: 1) Either would do fine. I only want values that reach thresh.
2) My understanding of the `previous` value is that it only has a value if the current value met the threshold.
3) I use it as a way to build a tuple of the nonzero indices.
4) Yes. That's what I want to do.
5) I want the value. I have another array that I already know will give me the index.
6) I will try your approach when I have the chance. It looks perfect, but I'm not very familiar with `itertools` or `izip` (I'm a newb).

Comment: Whoa! Thanks! That works like a charm! I didn't think it'd be so easy. Thanks again!